# Adding a WHERE condition breaks SQL ORDER BY sorting

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table definition similar to the following

```
MY_TABLE
==========================
PERSON_ID VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
ACTN_CD   VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
LOG_DATE  CHAR(10 BYTE)
...
```

Running the SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE PERSON_ID = '281385010' 
ORDER BY TO_DATE(LOG_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC, ACTN_CD;
```

returns the results below.

```
PERSON_ID ACTN_CD  LOG_DATE
--------- -------- ----------
281385010 COR-ML   06/28/2016
281385010 COR-ML   06/09/2016
281385010 AUD-01   06/08/2016
281385010 COR-PH   05/26/2016
281385010 AUD-01   05/24/2016
281385010 AUD-01   05/16/2016
281385010 TERM     05/03/2016
```

However, if I specify an ACTN_CD to match on in my statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE PERSON_ID = '281385010' 
AND ACTN_CD = 'AUD-01' 
ORDER BY TO_DATE(LOG_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC, ACTN_CD;
```

My ORDER BY clause seems to get ignored and the results are;

```
PERSON_ID ACTN_CD  LOG_DATE
--------- -------- ----------
281385010 AUD-01   05/16/2016
281385010 AUD-01   05/24/2016
281385010 AUD-01   06/08/2016
```

I am stumped as to why the addition of the ACTN_CD criteria would break my sort order.  Has anyone else seen behavior similar to this?

**EDIT**
To be precise, I am looking for the results to be sorted first by LOG_DATE DESCending then by ACTN_CD ASCending if there are multiple actions on a single date.  This works fine as long as ACTN_CD is not specified in the WHERE clause.  I can literally specify any other field in the table in the WHERE and it will not break this sorting.

**ISSUE RESOLVED**
I created another table with the same fields as the original and copied some of the data over.  Running the same SQL against this new table yielded the expected results so I started looking for differences.  It turns out that ACTN_CD was part of an index on the table.  Removing the index fixed the sorting issue.  I was unaware that sorting on an indexed field would cause problems, hopefully this will help someone else in the future.  Thanks all.

Comment: can you clarify?  It looks like the `LOG_DATE` is ordered correctly.

Comment: 05/16, 05/24, 06/18 is the correct order.

Comment: why do you have ACTN_CD in the order by

Comment: if it was ascending, sure... OP wants it sorted DESC (as the SQL shows)

Comment: @puzeledbysql, the SQL is created dynamically by a Java program, it was an over site on my part to not remove the needless ACTN_CD in that scenario, however it shouldn't affect the outcome.

Comment: This is a blind guess: The `TO_DATE()` function call does not actually return what you think it does, probably `NULL`. The order you see in both queries is effectively undefined and depends on the order the server decides the read the rows in. As you specify more conditions (`ACTN_CD`), the query plan changes, the rows are read in a different order and the - still ineffective - `ORDER BY` is still ineffective.

Comment: @user2722968, I've added the TO_DATE() as a field in the select and it does return valid date values so I don't think this is the problem.  Also, over the course of many runs it always returns results in DESC date order as long as ACTN_CD is not part of the criteria.

Comment: Did you get the actual query plan?

Comment: I've tried recreating this over but I can't replicate your results using the information you've given us. Table with those rows, column names, those rows of data, and the output is as you're hoping. There is a saved version of my code here: [rextester.com/GWLB67808](http://rextester.com/GWLB67808)

Comment: Unrelated, but: why on earth are you storing dates in a varchar column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, done.  As for the dates, I am simply doing the best with what I am given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another table with the same fields as the original and copied some of the data over. Running the same SQL against this new table yielded the expected results so I started looking for differences. It turns out that ACTN_CD was part of an index on the table. Removing the index fixed the sorting issue. I was unaware that sorting on an indexed field would cause problems, hopefully this will help someone else in the future. Thanks all.